# Modal Angular ng repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I trying to do a modal that show events in a table but when i do the ng-repeat only show one item and i don't know why.

If someone can help me i will be very grateful,
The html is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="dashboard">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>LiftEye</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
    <script src="../controllers/dashboardController.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular-tablescroll.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular-resource.js"></script>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="dashboardController">

<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-header -->

        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">

    <div id="page-wrapper" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Operación</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                <div class="panel " STYLE="background-color: #eaeaea">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">


                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- /.panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default" >
            <div class="panel-heading">

            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div >
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped dataTable no-footer" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
                                <tr role = "row" class="info text-center">
                                    <th ng-click="order('msisdn')">Número Teléfono</th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('icc')">ICC</th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('imei')">IMEI</th>
                                    <!--th>IMEI</th-->
                                    <th ng-click="order('ActivationStatus')">Estado</th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('sitename')">Instalación</th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('siteaddress')">Dirección</th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('sitecity')">Ciudad</th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('sitezip')">Código Postal</th>

                                    <th ng-click="order('phonedesc')">Modelo Teléfono</th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('ContractingMode')">VBP</th>


                                </tr>


                                <tr class=" text-center" ng-repeat-start="object in objects | filter:searchText | filter:tableFilter | orderBy:predicate:reverse" ng-click="main.activeRow = object.icc" >
                                    <td>{{object.msisdn}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.icc}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.imei}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.ActivationStatus}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.sitename}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.siteaddress}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.sitecity}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.sitezip}}</td>

                                    <td>{{object.phonedesc}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ object.ContractingMode ? 'Yes': 'No'}}</td>





                                </tr>

                                <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="main.activeRow==object.icc">
                                    <td colspan="3"> <a>Fecha Activación:</a> <div> {{object.DateActivation}}</div> <div><a> Fecha Baja</a> {{object.DateDisconnection}}</div> <div><a> Último Evento HW</a> {{object.LastHWEvent}}</div></td>
                                    <td colspan="4"> <a>Último Evento Humano:</a> <div> {{object.LastHumanEvent}}</div> <div><a> Último Evento Test</a> {{object.LastTestEvent}}</div> <a>Comentarios:</a> <div> {{object.comments}}</div> </td>
                                    <td colspan="2"> <div><a> Rae1: </a> {{object.rae1}}</div>  <div><a> Rae2: </a> {{object.rae2}}</div> <a>Pin1:</a> <div> {{object.pin1}}</div> <div><a> Pin2: </a> {{object.pin2}}</div></td>

                                    <td colspan="1"> <div> <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="open(object)">Eventos</button></div>  </td>
                                    <div >
                                        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h3 class="modal-title">Eventos</h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body"  >
                                                <table class="table" ng-tablescroll="options">
                                                    <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th >Fecha</th>
                                                        <th >Tipo Evento</th>
                                                        <th >Origen Evento</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    <tr ng-repeat="evento in eventos | limitTo:5">

                                                        <td>{{evento.eventtime}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{evento.eventtype}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{evento.parenttype}}</td>


                                                    </tr></tbody></table>


                                            </div>


                                            <div class="modal-footer">

                                                <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </script>


                                    </div>
                                </tr>




                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.table-responsive -->




                    </div>

                </div>






            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-body -->
        </div>

        <!-- /.panel -->

        <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

And the controller is the following. The modal is inside a table with parent child.

```
var app =angular.module('dashboard',['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('dashboardController', function($scope, $http,$modal ){
    $scope.objects=[{}];
    $scope.objects={};
    $scope.objects=[];
    $scope.grupos =[{}];
    $scope.longitud =[{}];
    $scope.eventos =[{}];

    var URLEvents = "/api/events/";
//Abrimos modal y les pasamos los eventos de esa instalación
    $scope.open = function (object) {

        $http.get(URLEvents + object.liftsiteid, $scope)
            .success(function (data) {
                var events = data;

                angular.forEach(events, function(event) {
                    $scope.eventos = event;
                    var modalInstance = $modal.open({

                        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                        size: 'lg',
                        resolve: {
                            items: function () {
                                return $scope.eventos;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                })
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                window.alert('Something Wrong...');
            });


    };

    var URLOperation ="/api/sites";


//Funci?n que devuelve las instalaciones de un usuario
    $http.get(URLOperation, $scope)
        .success(function(data) {
            var groups = data;
            angular.forEach(groups, function(group) {
                var group2 = group;
                angular.forEach(group2.sites, function(group3){
                    $scope.longitud.push(group3);
                    $scope.objects.push(group3);
                    $scope.predicate = 'msisdn';
                    $scope.reverse = true;
                    $scope.order = function(predicate) {
                        $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
                        $scope.predicate = predicate;
                    };
                })
            });
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            window.alert('Something Wrong...');
        });


});

//Abrimos el modal y le enviamos los eventos
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items, $anchorScroll){
    $anchorScroll();
    $scope.eventos =[{}];
    $scope.eventos.push(items);

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

[image]

Comment: you might wanna post just the relevant sections mate, hard to follow the code without spending too much time on it.

Answer (score 2):

You're providing a lot of code - do you have the same issue for all of your lists and tables?

My first guess would be the initialization of the arrays:

```
$scope.grupos =[{}];
```

Try setting an empty array instead of an array with the first element being empty:

```
$scope.grupos = [];
```

Since you push new elements into the arrays when receiving your data, the first empty item will always be stuck in the data and might lead to your issues.

Another issue is in getting the "eventos": `$scope.eventos = event;`

I think this should be a push instead: `$scope.eventos.push(event);`

No offense - maybe you should try to get a better understanding of these basic concepts in Javascript (you're already using most of them correctly, but some look kind of mixed up):

- Object initialization: `var obj = {};` - this would be an empty object with no properties.
- Array initialization: `var arr = [];` - this would be an empty array with no elements.

Therefore `var x = [{}]` will result in `x` being an array with an empty object.

Comment: Thanks. I simplified the code but still only showing one item and i have more than one. Now the first empty item dissapears but still the problem

Comment: Ok - now that I know it's about the events: replace $scope.eventos = event; with the push, I have extended the answer.

Comment: Thank you!! i had to changes some things more but now it work's

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to open one modal per event rather than one modal for all of the events.

Try replacing:

```
var events = data;

angular.forEach(events, function(event) {
    $scope.eventos = event;
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
       templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
       controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
       size: 'lg',
       resolve: {
           items: function () {
               return $scope.eventos;
           }
       }
   });
})
```

with

```
$scope.eventos = data;
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
    size: 'lg',
    resolve: {
       items: function () {
           return $scope.eventos;
       }
   }
});
```

and replace your modal instance with:

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items, $anchorScroll){
    $anchorScroll();
    $scope.eventos = items;

    $scope.cancel = function () {
       $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
 });
```